# Do I need to fit on train data for truncated SVD and then transform the test data on fitted train data?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

Regarding truncated SVD(single value decomposition) do I need to fit on train data and transform the test data on fitted train data? or can I fit on test and transform on test fit?